# Get Website text from URL into String (Android)

Tags: java, android

first of all I have to say that I'm a beginner in Android programing and not very experienced in general programing at all. But now I decided to make a little app for my private use.

In my app I need to get some Text from a given URL into a string. I found some methods on the web and personalized them a bit. But there is something wrong because when I run the app with the Android Eclipse emulator it says "Unfortunately, xxx_app has stopped.".

Here is my code:

```
    public String getURLtext(String zielurl) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
    String meineurl = zielurl;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(meineurl);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          response.getEntity().getContent()
        )
      );

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      result += line + "\n";
    }

    return result;          
}
```

And this is the method where I want to show the output string in my EditText text1.

```
public void test(View view) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IllegalStateException, IOException {

EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textfeld);
String teststring = getURLtext("http://ephemeraltech.com/demo/android_tutorial20.php");
text1.setText(teststring);


}
```

I would be happy if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: When you get an error, always look at the logcat which should show the cause. If you can't see that window, in Eclipse use Window -> ShowView -> Logcat. One issue, as already answered, is network on main thread. Having addressed that, if you have further errors please update your question with the logcat output.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good until you get the HTTPResponse, the bottom part (response to string) can be optimized a lot. It's also worth noticing that Android [won't let you to do network operation on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception), so please consider using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to execute your http GET operation.

```
public String getURLtext(String zielurl) throws IllegalStateException, IOException

{
    String result = ""; // default empty string
    try
    {
        String meineurl = zielurl;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(meineurl);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);

    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    result = inputStreamToString(is).toString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // do some Log.e here
    }
    finally
    {
        return result;          
    }
}

// Fast Implementation
private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return full string
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I copied the code and pasted it into my Android Eclipse project and tried to test it again. This time there is no error but when I click the button the text field remains blank and nothing happens.

Comment: What if you add ex.printStackTrace(); in the catch block? Have you tried an AsyncTask as I suggested?